# Make maven clean not fail when only folder remains

Tags: maven, maven-clean-plugin

While developing an application, the command I use most often is `mvn clean install`. Cleaning probably isn't needed 90% of the time, but it does not hurt and might help to avoid weird issues. There are however times, when I'm working on a console application, when I have trunk open on one terminal, and target on another.

`mvn clean` in such a case does what I need it to - it deletes every file within the target folder - and then fails due to lock on the folder itself. Is there a way to tell it, that in such a case it should just ignore/skip deleting the folder itself and continue with `install`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure the [`maven-clean-plugin` to ignore errors](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/ignoring-errors.html) with the help of the [`failOnError`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#failOnError) attribute. It defaults to `true`, meaning that the plugin will fail on error.

Sample configuration to disable this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can also do it directly on the command line, without changing the POM, by setting the `maven.clean.failOnError` user property:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false
```

Note that this make the plugin ignore all errors, however it is not currently possible to make it ignore only certain types of errors.